# Suggested order to read HP Lovecraft

Tags: suggested-order, h-p-lovecraft

In the [help](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I read a good reason to ask a question is *franchise/series reading or viewing order*.

The thing is, I've bought some of Lovecraft's books for my mother, and she appreciated the first one I bought, *At the mountains of madness*, the most (*by a long shot* she says).

Therefore I was wondering whether I've really picked up the best book or, in other words, the book which would generally be suggested as the last one to read.

These are the other books I've bought.

- Single book with

  - *The Horror at Red Hook*
  - *The Call of Cthulhu*
- *The Case of Charles Dexter Ward*
- Single book with

  - *The Dunwich Horror*
  - *The Colour Out of Space*
  - *The Curse of Yig*

Comment: [Very Possible duplicate: What's the best order to read HP Lovecraft's novels?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2339/58193) [Also related: In what order should I read the 'extended' Cthulhu Mythos?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/25171/58193)

Comment: They look like pretty perfect duplicates to me - how are they different?

Comment: If you are not aware, all Lovecraft's fiction is available online now (generally with typos corrected):  https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/

Comment: @Buzz, I had absolutely no idea! Thank you very much :)